# WPF object binding from parent itemscontrol

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding

I have Groups collection property in my viewmodel and each group has its Teams collection.
I want to remove a team from group with a button click. How can I bind the group in which the team is to the command parameter? This solution is not working:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Groups}" Name="gSource" Tag="{Binding .}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>

            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>

                    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Teams}" Name="tSource">
                        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical"/>
                            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>

                        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>

                                <Button Command="{Binding Path=DataContext.RemoveTeamFromGroupCommand, ElementName=gSource}">
                                    <Button.CommandParameter>
                                        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource ObjectsConverter}">
                                            <Binding Path="."/>
                                            <Binding Path="Tag.Value" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource  AncestorType=ItemsControl}"/>
                                        </MultiBinding>
                                    </Button.CommandParameter>
                                </Button>

                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl>

                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
```

It binds the team properly, but instead of group it binds MS.Internal.NamedObject with unset value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Tam Bui is perfectly right about using the DataContext of the parent ItemsControl.
But besides "RelativeSource AncestorType", you can name the UI elements inside the DataTemplate (you assigned the tSource) and use them.
You used a similar binding to bind the command.
Also, Binding by default provides a link to the current data context.
It is not necessary to give it Path.
Alternative solution:

```
    <Button Command="{Binding Path=DataContext.RemoveTeamFromGroupCommand, ElementName=gSource}">
        <Button.CommandParameter>
            <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource ObjectsConverter}">
                <Binding/>
                <Binding Path="DataContext" ElementName="tSource"/>
            </MultiBinding>
        </Button.CommandParameter>
    </Button>
```

Answer (score 1):

The `Tag` is unnecessary if you want the Group to be the 2nd binding of your MultiBinding.  Instead, just bind it to the `DataContext` of the relative ancestor `ItemsControl`.  I tested this and it worked.

```
<MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource ObjectsConverter}">
    <Binding Path="."/>
    <Binding Path="DataContext" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource  AncestorType=ItemsControl}"/>
</MultiBinding>
```